# Xcode Can't Call/Dismiss viewcontroller from PopUp

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is going to take some explaining... So I'll do it in order:

1. I have a navigation controller where the rootViewController is called TipsCollectionViewController.
2. I have a UserViewController that's loaded as a popup:

   UserViewController * userView = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
                           [userView setUEmail:email];
                           [self presentPopupViewController:userView animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopBottom];
3. I then have another popup that loads on top of THAT popup:

   Place *p = [placeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   ```
   DetailPlaceViewController *pvc = [[DetailPlaceViewController alloc] init];
   [pvc setPlace:p];
   NSLog(@"%@", p.PName);
   [self presentPopupViewController:pvc animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopBottom];
   ```

Now there's a reason I've done this: the AppDelegate features a Navigation controller and previously I loaded the UserView like this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:userView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But this meant that the UserView would load on the iPhone but not on the iPad for some odd reason. But when I switched it to the popup view it worked fine.

So now I load both the UserView and the DetailPlaceView in a popup... but now it CLOSES on the iPad but not on the iPhone.

Here's the code for closing the detail view:

```
- (void) didTapBackButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"View Controller Number: %lu", (unsigned long)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
    if(self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        NSArray *stack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
        TipCollectionViewController *tipsVC = stack[stack.count-1];
        [tipsVC.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

I know there's a better way to handle this whole thing... but what should I be doing differently?

**UPDATE**

If I switch it back to:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:userview animated:YES];
```

...for the UserView on the iPhone and:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

...for the view that loads after that, then the UserView will load... but the next viewcontroller (the DetailPlaceViewController) won't load. I think that's my main problem.  I could probably dismiss the second view controller at that point if I could get it to load. Any ideas?

Comment: That was a bit confusing, i know you tried to clear it up though. Could you explain in further detail why you switched to the former method, as it seems a bit more convoluted? If you could expand on that more I could help

Comment: Ok.  Well the problem was that the UserView (a typical user page) always loaded just fine as a navigationController stack on the iPhone... but wouldn't load at all on the iPad.  So after experimenting with various things I discovered that it would load as a popupview on both. So now you have that popupview and you need to load another view (in this case an item from a collection view) well that would only load from another popupview. So that's how I got to where I'm at.

Comment: Another thing. If I switch it back to [self.navigationController pushViewController:userview animated:YES]; and [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES]; then the UserView will load... but the next viewcontroller (the DetailPlaceViewController) won't load. I think that's my main problem.  I've switched it now so that it loads the popup for the iPad and the regular navigation controller for the iPhone, but it just won't load that second screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately all I had to do was switch:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

to:

```
[self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES];
```

And it works.  It opens and closes the view and everything works as it should.

I'm getting a warning on the DetailView once you click an item:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UserViewController: 0x16e02020>
```

So I'll wait a couple of days to accept my answer. Otherwise, despite the warning, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self presentPopupViewController:pvc animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopBottom];
```

if you are using this,presentPopupViewController is used to display like modal view which cant be dismissed without any custom cancellation action.

To use popOverViewController method, use pushViewController. Then that one you can dismiss by this technique.

Comment: I'm getting the error "incompatible pointer types sending UIPopOverController to parameter type "UserView"

Comment: UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                     initWithContentViewController:pvc];
    aPopover.delegate = self;
    
    [self presentViewController:aPopover animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Updated my question to explain things a bit better.